# nontype template parameter why can not pass std::vector

Tags: c++

I am trying with the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename T, std::vector <T> myV>
int fun()
{
  cout <<" Inside fun () "<<endl;
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv)
{
  std::vector<int> a;
  fun<int,a>();
}
```

I can not pass std::vector  myV  ?

But  instead of **std::vector , i could able to use something like template 
****, and **fun().**

Answer (score 1):

What goes in triangular brackets must be a type or a compile-time constant; it cannot be a variable. Although `a`'s type is `vector<int>`, `a` itself is an object of type `vector<int>`; it cannot go in triangular brackets as one of template parameters.

In addition, you cannot use `vector<T>` as a second type parameter of your template function: `vector<T>` is a type which becomes fully known once you know `T`. Since you already have `T` as your template parameter, you can declare `vector<T>` "for free" inside your function without an additional template parameter.

Finally, in C++11 you can get a type of a variable statically using [`decltype`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype). For example, if you modify your code to take a single type parameter of `T`, you could do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
int fun()
{
  cout <<" Inside fun () "<<endl;
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv)
{
  std::vector<int> a;
  // This is the same as calling fun<std::vector<int> >();
  fun<decltype(a)>();
  return 0;
}
```

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/It8pRT).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. is it possible to use std::vector<int> as a template parameter?. because std::vector<int> itself an data type right?. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Whoami Yes, it is possible to use `std::vector<int>` as a template parameter: any type, including ones based on templates. What you cannot use is `std::vector` (with no `<int>` or other type parameter) because it is a template name, not a type.

Comment: so, std::vector is a class template, std::vector<int> is its specialization which is a valid data type. if we still want to provide std::vector, then we need to go with template-template parameter concept. is that so ?

Comment: @Whoami In some cases you can use default type arguments, for example, [like this](http://ideone.com/WMUQ4r). You can also use template-template parameters, but the situations where you want to use them are different.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call

```
fun<int, std::vector<int>>();
```

which passes the **type** `std::vector<int>`. If you want to pass an instance (`a`) of `std::vector<int>`, you will have to change your function definition to:

```
template<typename T>
int fun(std::vector<T> v)
{
    std::cout << "Inside fun()\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a;
    fun(a);
}
```